# Prevent fonts to be embedded in webpack generated css

Tags: css, webpack, fonts, sass

I have recently need to use fonts from local application which were earlier referenced from http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans, earlier fonts were referenced in sass like :

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Maven+Pro");
```

I installed fonts from npm & imported in sass like:

```
 @import url("../node_modules/typeface-maven-pro?family=Maven+Pro");
```

Now webpack is generating 21MB css which earlier was 320kb. As I supspected upon inspection I found fonts are embedded in css as hexadecimal like :

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: url(data:application/vnd.ms-fontobject;base64,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);
```

Please note I have to truncate font in encoded text as question character limit is 30000 characters in stack overflow & there are multiple font faces like this.

What is wrong here?

Comment: What plugin are you using to deal with fonts? I never had problems using the `extract-text-webpack-plugin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue was with my loader for fonts as used for fonts. I was using `url-loader` like:

```
{
     test: /\.(jpg|png|gif|eot|woff2|woff|ttf|ico|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
     loader: 'url-loader'
}
```

**Solution** is to modify it limit file size and split the bigger files like :

```
{
   test: /\.(woff2|woff|ttf|eot|svg|otf)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
   loaders: ["url-loader?limit=100&name=fonts/[name]_[hash].[ext]"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone deals with this while using [Sensible webpack 5 boilerplate](https://github.com/taniarascia/webpack-boilerplate) . I solved it by changing the **type**

from

```
{ test: /\.(woff(2)?|eot|ttf|otf|svg|)$/, type: 'asset/inline' }
```

to

```
{ test: /\.(woff(2)?|eot|ttf|otf|svg|)$/, type: 'asset/resource' },
```

nb: also puts svgs separate. You can modify the test